# Linux system call getname info return EAI_AGAIN

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

In my C++ application I use `getnameinfo` and it returns `EAI_AGAIN` - what causes this error?

```
struct sockaddr_storage ss;
socklen_t salen = sizeof(ss);
struct sockaddr *sa;
struct addrinfo hints, *paddr, *paddrp;

sa = (struct sockaddr *)&ss;

if (getpeername(sock, sa, &salen) != 0) {
    error = errno;
    return -1;
}

char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST];
char pbuf[NI_MAXSERV];
if (0 != (error = getnameinfo(sa, salen,
                  hbuf, sizeof(hbuf),
                  pbuf, sizeof(pbuf),
                  0))) {
    return -1;//here it returns, the error is -3=EAI_AGAIN
}
```

Comment: but what can cause it? my application can't wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [getnameinfo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getnameinfo.html):

> [EAI_AGAIN] The name could not be resolved at this time. Future attempts may succeed.

The most likely reason would be some kind of timeout during the DNS lookup.

Comment: So what can I do in order to fix it?

Comment: Future attempts not succeeded

Comment: You just have to live with the possibility that DNS lookups can fail.

Comment: Note to cmeerw. Yes DNS lookups can fail and EAI_AGAIN will be returned. However, when this call continuously returns EAI_AGAIN even when lookups work from the command line and a restart of the service fixes it is indicating another issue.